# Python sum subarray based on another array bool condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays

```
a=['1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '1', '', '', '1']

b=[118.27316896, 112.86004695, 216.49303595, 154.6773138 ,
       316.30213565,  97.63585819, 241.84038063, 134.33425789,
       209.5535334 ,  77.92662544,  81.30731218, 142.5126865 ]
```

I want to create 3rd array which sums values in sub-array of b based on values from array a.
So, for array members c this would be:

```
c[0]=sum(b[0:6]) = 1258.082
c[2]=sum(b[7:8]) = 343.88
c[3]=sum(b[9:11]) = 301.74
```

Finally new array c with following content:

```
 c= [1258.08,343.88,301.74]
```

I know how to create bool from `a` array, but i cant get any further than that.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: how do you get the values in C  ? what is 1139.8 ? it is definitely not the sum of `b[0:2]`

Comment: You need to explain how the values in `c` are derived from `a` and `b`.

Comment: We didn't understand what you want, and how to derive c from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, First [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy-cumsum) then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group on `cumsum values`

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

a = ['1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '1', '', '', '1']

b = [118.27316896, 112.86004695, 216.49303595, 154.6773138,
     316.30213565, 97.63585819, 241.84038063, 134.33425789,
     209.5535334, 77.92662544, 81.30731218, 142.5126865]

a_cs = np.cumsum(np.array(a) == '1')
# a -> [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4]

g = groupby(zip(a_cs, b), key = lambda x: x[0])
# {1: [(1, 118.27316896), (1, 112.86004695)..], 2: [(2, 134.33425789)..],...}

print(
    [sum(yy[1] for yy in y) for _, y in g]
)
```

---

```
[1258.08194013, 343.88779129, 301.74662412]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.cumsum` on `b` and then access those values based on `a` to get the total sum from the beginning.

```py
cs = np.cumsum(b)[a == '1']
```

To start the sum from the last `'1'` get the difference to the previous `cumsum`

```py
cs_prev = [0, *cs[:-1]]
cs - cs_prev
```

You're `a` variable actually has length 13. I'm able to get simmilar results by shortening `a` by `1`. I believe it to be a typo, otherwise you will need to adapt this algorithm as `np.cumsum(b)[a == '1']` will fail due to too many boolean indices.